# Why is the format of CMD in a Dockerfile seem like a list of commands?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a few Dockferfile examples I am seeing this weird command format:

```
CMD [ "django-admin", "startproject hello_world_django" ]

CMD [ "python", "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

but in my own `Dockerfile`, I did this and it worked fine:

```
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

Dockerfile [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) state:

> The CMD instruction has three forms:

- > CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred
- > CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
- > CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)

> If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the  will execute
>   in /bin/sh -c:
>
> `FROM ubuntu CMD echo "This is a test." | wc`
>
> If you want to run your
>    without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON
>   array and give the full path to the executable. This array form is the
>   preferred format of CMD. Any additional parameters must be
>   individually expressed as strings in the array:
>
> `FROM ubuntu CMD ["/usr/bin/wc","--help"]`